# Python:Retrieve chunk of a zip file and process

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, io

I need to unzip large zip files (Approx. size ~10 GB) and put it back on S3. I have a memory limitation of 512 MB.

I tried this code and getting a `MemoryError` at `line: 9` where it loads the entire file content into memory and hence the this memory error. How to retrieve a chunk of the zip file, unzip it and upload it back to S3?

```
import json
import boto3
import io
import zipfile

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name="bucket.name", key="test/big.zip")
    buffer = io.BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)

    for filename in z.namelist():
        s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
            z.open(filename),
            Bucket="bucket.name",
            Key=f'{"test/" + filename}'
        )
```

Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest launch an EC2 instance with a predefined script in UserData of [run instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances) api using Lambda function, so that you can specify location file_name, etc in the script. In the script you can download zip from S3 and unzip using linux commands and then recursively upload entire folder to S3.

You can choose RAM/ROM as per your zip file size, post that you can stop you instance via the same script.

Comment: We need a serverless approach and using EC2 is not allowed, hence I was following this : https://medium.com/@multiaki/unzipping-s3-files-back-to-s3-without-uncompressing-entire-file-streaming-82f662b5065a. Since we use Python, can you suggest what is the alternative of NodeJS `.createReadStream()` in Python as mention in that URL?